# Install a global Drush via Composer

Tags: drupal, drush

I entered `vi ~/.bash_profile`, but the file is not empty. Where should I put `export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`?

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
PATH=$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$HOME/bin:$PATH

export PATH
```

I simply do this in one line (note I have Homebrew's path where you have $HOME/bin):

```
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```